# Pulling Variable from variable in URL stored in DB

Tags: php

If $youtubeurl = http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytWAw6YqN10S

How do I create a "v" variable and have it extract it from $youtubeurl

Example:
I have the youtube url stored in the DB but when I am embedding the player the URL needs to be formatted like

www.youtube.com/v/ytWAw6YqN10?fs=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way is to use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to extract the query string, and [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to fetch the `v` variable from it.

```
$youtubeurl = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytWAw6YqN10S";
$values = array();

$query_string = parse_url($youtubeurl, PHP_URL_QUERY); // extract query string

parse_str($query_string, $values); // turn query string into associative array

echo $values["v"]; // will echo "ytWAw6YqN10S"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular-expressions like:

```
preg_match_all("/^http://www.youtube.com/watch\?v=(.*).*/", $youtubeurl, $matches);
```

where $matches will be an array containing the matches within () i.e. variable v.

I am not sure about the expression I have given, but I am sure that this idea will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $youtubeurl = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytWAw6YqN10S";
 $pos = strpos($youtubeurl, "?v=");
 $v = "";
 if($pos !== FALSE)
 {
     $v = substr($youtubeurl, $pos + 3);
 }

 // now $v should contain the value you needed provided the url was valid
```