# How to extract only parameter value from URL using ONLY Regular Expressions

Tags: php, regex

Extract the value of the u2 parameter from this URL using a regular expression. http://www.example.com?u1=US&u2=HA853&u3=HPA

```
<?php
$subject="http://www.example.com?u1=US&u2=HA853&u3=HPA"; //my url
$pattern='/u2=[0-9A-Za-z]*/'; //R.E that url value is only digit/Alphabet 
preg_match($pattern,$subject,$match);
print_r($match[0]);
?>
```

Output:-
u2=HA853

How can i retrieve only HA853?

Comment: Why to use regular expression ? Just use $_GET['u2']

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pulling Variable from variable in URL stored in DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874380/pulling-variable-from-variable-in-url-stored-in-db)

Comment: i was trying to achieve the result only using Regular expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `0` group is everything that the regex matched so either use `\K` to ignore the previous matches of the regex,

```
$subject="http://www.example.com?u1=US&u2=HA853&u3=HPA"; //my url
$pattern='/u2=\K[0-9A-Za-z]*/'; //R.E that url value is only digit/Alphabet 
preg_match($pattern,$subject,$match);
print_r($match[0]);
```

or use a second capture group:

```
...
$pattern='/u2=([0-9A-Za-z]*)/'; //R.E that url value is only digit/Alphabet 
...
print_r($match[1]);
```

Why you'd need to do that though is unclear to me, http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php, seems like a simpler approach.

```
$subject="http://www.example.com?u1=US&u2=HA853&u3=HPA";
parse_str($subject, $output);
echo $output['u2'];
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/gR4cb

Comment: Thanks. The second capture group worked for me. Actually i was trying to retrieve the values only using Regular Expressions, so i have done that.

Answer (score 1):

Other way is to use parse_url,http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
  $subject="http://www.example.com?u1=US&u2=HA853&u3=HPA";
  $query_string  = parse_url($subject, PHP_URL_QUERY); // get query string
  $parameters  = explode('&', $query_string); //Explode with &
  $array  = array();  // define an empty array
  foreach($parameters  as $val)
   {
    $param= explode('=', $val);
    $array[$param[0]] = $param[1];
   }
  echo $array['u2']; // outputs HA853

print_r($array);

Array
(
    [u1] => US
    [u2] => HA853
    [u3] => HPA
)
```

Comment: @FirstOne I agree parse_Str is best